# how to retrieve specific child with parent entity using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate Named Query. GetEmployerWithActiveEmployeeList

```
public class Employer {
.
.
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Employee> employee;
.
.
}



  public class Employee {
...
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name = "employer_id")
private Employer employer;

...
   }
```

Now I want to write named query to fetchEmployerWithActiveEmployee

My Named Query is like this

```
"from Employer employer left join employer.employees emp where employer.id=:employerId and emp.status = 1"
```

when i inspect employer object it gives me shows me all employee.

Is this possible in hibernate ?

Comment: if using just hibernate and not relying on jpa, you can look into @Formula annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your query selects those employers that have at least one active employee. However, this "active employee" condition is just a criteria. The selected Employer object still contains all employees.

You probably want something like this:

```
select emp from Employer employer left join employer.employees emp where employer.id=:employerId and emp.status = 1
```

(note the "select emp")
Then the result should be a list of Employee objects.

Comment: No Dear This is not my requirement. I want get employer by id , And Only associated Active Employee should come with employer.

Comment: That's not way an ORM like Hibernate mapper works. If you load an entity (using a query whatsoever) then you will always see all associated relationships. If only the active employees would be in the `employee` set of an `Employer` then this would be a different entity.